# offset camera Focus on player

Tags: coronasdk, perspectivecamera

I have some issue I have difficulties to handle,
I've made a camera as follow focus on the player, at constant distance

```
self.gameGroup.x = - player.physics.x + 200
```

So until there my camera follows my player moving at constant speed, as expected, but for some gameplay issue, I need to move my player on the right or in the left while the speed keep the same value just my player move into the right or left ( a bit like a space shooter Game [what I expect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STpBfk7perE) ).

I think in space shooter that's the background who is moving while the player are not moving, for myself this is my player moving but not the backGround (to save memory) so here is the issue.

If someOne can explain me the logic behind this I would apreciate it, it should be some group handling I think but I'm a bit confused..

I can give some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This game is very similar to my first Corona SDK game that I published. Basically you don't need a camera for this. Draw your ship at the left edge. Constrain it's movement to keep it in the left 3rd of the screen.

The game objects move with transitions to move them right to left. The background can be moved with transitions, though using an enterFrame listener to move the background at its own pace.